# Java write to ResourceBundle

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Is it possible to write back to a ResourceBundle? Currently I am using a ResourceBundle to store information, at runtime it is read using the following

```
while(ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundleName").getKeys().hasMoreElements()){

//output

}
```

Should I not be using a ResourceBundle if I wish to write to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like by default this is not the case, but you can pass an instance of [ResourceBundle.Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) to ResourceBundle.getBundle to use a custom subclass of ResourceBundle that would expose a setKey method that lets you set the keys.

Comment: After reading the documentation I am not really using ResourceBundle for its intended purpose.. Looks like it should contain local information. Was just using this type of file because its loaded into memory by this application I am customizing. Thanks for the information. Might just be better to store my information in a CSV as it is unrelated to locales

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, you can also store settings in a properties file, load that into a Properties object, and then change the properties at runtime as needed.